# Is there a way to make this query more efficient performance wise?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

This query takes a long time to run on MS Sql 2008 DB with 70GB of data.
If i run the 2 where clauses seperately it takes a lot less time.

EDIT - I need to change the 'select *' to 'delete' afterwards, please keep it in mind when answering. thanks :)

```
select *
From computers
Where Name in
      (
      select T2.Name
      from 
            (
            select Name
            from computers
            group by Name
            having COUNT(*) > 1
            ) T3 
      join computers T2 on T3.Name = T2.Name 
      left join policyassociations PA on T2.PK = PA.EntityId
      where (T2.EncryptionStatus = 0 or T2.EncryptionStatus is NULL) and 
            (PA.EntityType <> 1 or PA.EntityType is NULL)
      )
OR
      ClientId in
      (
      select substring(ClientID,11,100)
      from computers
      )
```

Comment: Replace the `IN( subquery )` by an `exists ( subquery )` (t2 and t3 are never referenced by the outer query, and t2 and t3 have the the same purpose, their product is a cartesian product.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swapping `IN` for `EXISTS` will help.
Also, as per Gordon's answer: `UNION` can out-perform `OR`.

```
SELECT computers.*
FROM   computers
 LEFT
  JOIN policyassociations
    ON policyassociations.entityid = computers.pk
WHERE  (
          computers.encryptionstatus = 0
       OR computers.encryptionstatus IS NULL
       )
AND    (
          policyassociations.entitytype <> 1
       OR policyassociations.entitytype IS NULL
       )
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT name
         FROM   (
                 SELECT name
                 FROM   computers
                 GROUP
                     BY name
                 HAVING Count(*) > 1
                ) As duplicate_computers
         WHERE  name = computers.name
       )

UNION

SELECT *
FROM   computers As c
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT SubString(clientid, 11, 100)
         FROM   computers
         WHERE  SubString(clientid, 11, 100) = c.clientid
       )
```

---

You've now updated your question asking to make this a delete.

Well the good news is that instead of the "OR" you just make two `DELETE` statements:

```
DELETE
FROM   computers
 LEFT
  JOIN policyassociations
    ON policyassociations.entityid = computers.pk
WHERE  (
          computers.encryptionstatus = 0
       OR computers.encryptionstatus IS NULL
       )
AND    (
          policyassociations.entitytype <> 1
       OR policyassociations.entitytype IS NULL
       )
AND    EXISTS (
         SELECT name
         FROM   (
                 SELECT name
                 FROM   computers
                 GROUP
                     BY name
                 HAVING Count(*) > 1
                ) As duplicate_computers
         WHERE  name = computers.name
       )
;

DELETE
FROM   computers As c
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT SubString(clientid, 11, 100)
         FROM   computers
         WHERE  SubString(clientid, 11, 100) = c.clientid
       )
;
```

Comment: returns the following error -
Msg 205, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Comment: @Morrtz edited, try now. I was being lazy (and I don't know the table sctructure) and using `SELECT *`. You should *always* list out your columns

Comment: I've edited the post, added that I would need to change the select to a delete afterwards so please check before answering as I cannot use the union.

Comment: How many rows are you trying to delete in a single go? Bear in mind that deleting a large dataset will take even longer (writing to log file, locks, etc, etc, etc). You may want to look in to batching your deletes.

Comment: Your new query is exponentially faster, what took me around 30 minutes now takes under a minute.

Comment: Usually no more than 2000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

`or` can be poorly optimized sometimes.  In this case, you can just split the query into two subqueries, and combine them using `union`:

```
select *
From computers
Where Name in
      (
      select T2.Name
      from 
            (
            select Name
            from computers
            group by Name
            having COUNT(*) > 1
            ) T3 
      join computers T2 on T3.Name = T2.Name 
      left join policyassociations PA on T2.PK = PA.EntityId
      where (T2.EncryptionStatus = 0 or T2.EncryptionStatus is NULL) and 
            (PA.EntityType <> 1 or PA.EntityType is NULL)
      )
UNION
select *
From computers
WHERE ClientId in
      (
      select substring(ClientID,11,100)
      from computers
      );
```

You might also be able to improve performance by replacing the subqueries with explicit `join`s.  However, this seems like the shortest route to better performance.

EDIT:

I think the version with join's is:

```
select c.*
From computers c left outer join
     (select c.Name
      from (select c.*, count(*) over (partition by Name) as cnt
            from computers c
           ) c left join
           policyassociations PA
           on T2.PK = PA.EntityId and PA.EntityType <> 1
      where (c.EncryptionStatus = 0 or c.EncryptionStatus is NULL) and
            c.cnt > 1
     ) cpa
     on c.Name = cpa.Name left outer join
     (select substring(ClientID, 11, 100) as name
      from computers
     ) csub
     on c.Name = csub.name 
Where cpa.Name is not null or csub.Name is not null;
```

Comment: error when running -
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "T2.PK" could not be bound.

Comment: I've edited the post, added that I would need to change the select to a delete afterwards so please check before answering as I cannot use trhe

Answer (score 0):

Some things I would look at are
1. are indexes in place?
2. 'IN' will slow your query, try replacing it with joins,
3. you should use column name, I guess 'Name' in this case, while using count(*),
4. try selecting required data only, by selecting particular columns.

Hope this helps!